# Как правильно сделать удалённый вызов используя средства JPDA

Tags: java

Есть приложение, которое средствами JPDA коннектиться к другому (на котором настроен debug: `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8858`).

Я получаю инстанс `VirtualMachine` удаленного приложения используя `SocketAttachingConnector` (подключаясь к 8858-порту).

На всякий случай выставляю на объекте виртуальной машины `setDebugTraceMode(VirtualMachine.TRACE_EVENTS)` (пока не понял, влияет ли это ещё на что либо, кроме дебага в стандартных sout/serr).

Сам инстанс `VirtualMachine` содержит действительно актуальную информацию о удаленном приложении (потоки, классы и тп), однако я не могу сделать удаленный вызов метода на удаленном объекте (как статические так и обычные методы).

Вот элементарный код, которым я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
    List<ReferenceType> list = vm.allClasses().stream().filter(str -> str.name().equals("java.lang.Runtime")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ReferenceType runtime = list.get(0);
    ObjectReference or = runtime.instances(0).get(0);
    Method method = runtime.allMethods().stream().filter(m -> m.name().contains("freeMemory")).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
    ThreadReference th = vm.allThreads().stream().filter(thread -> thread.name().contains("main")).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
    System.out.println(or.invokeMethod(th, method1, new ArrayList<>(), ObjectReference.INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED));
```

- В коде получаю инстанс `Runtime` - объект есть, на первый взгляд всё в
  порядке
- Беру у него ссылку на метод `freeMemory()` - тоже все
  выглядит хорошо
- Получаю ссылку на main-поток - все хорошо
- На объекте `or` (`Runtime` удаленного приложения) вызываю метод `method` - получаю ошибку `Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jdi.IncompatibleThreadStateException`

При этом получение локальный переменных (даже private) проходит на ура.

Вопросы:

1. В каком стейте должен находиться удаленный поток, чтобы в нем можно
   было сделать удаленный вызов? В документации [ObjectReference](http://srcrr.com/java/oracle/openjdk/6/reference/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html#invokeMethod(com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference,%20com.sun.jdi.Method,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20com.sun.jdi.Value%3E,%20int))
   есть указание, что поток должен быть в suspend, но не обычном, а
   вызванным каким-либо ивентом в этом потоке. Что это за ивенты и как
   ими управлять?
2. Как правильно организовать удаленный вызов средствами
   JDI (некий аналог Watches в IntelliJ IDEA).
3. Есть ли у кого-нибудь материал по данной теме. В стандартной комплектации JDK есть парочка примеров, но их совершенно недостаточно для того, чтобы ознакомиться сданной платформой. Более-менее внятных статей тоже не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

> В каком стейте должен находиться удаленный поток, чтобы в нем можно было сделать удаленный вызов? В документации ObjectReference есть указание, что поток должен быть в suspend, но не обычном, а вызванным каким-либо ивентом в этом потоке. Что это за ивенты и как ими управлять?

Ниже фрагмент кода, использующего удалённые треды и  ивенты:

```
    private VirtualMachine launchTarget( String command ) throws IOException
    {
        final LaunchingConnector connector = findLaunchingConnector();
        final Map<String, Argument> arguments = connectorArguments( connector, command );
        try
        {
            return connector.launch( arguments );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new Error( "Unable to launch target VM: " + e );
        }
        catch ( IllegalConnectorArgumentsException e )
        {
            throw new Error( "Internal error: " + e );
        }
        catch ( VMStartException e )
        {
            throw new Error( "Target VM failed to initialize: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private LaunchingConnector findLaunchingConnector()
    {
        final List<Connector> connectors = Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager().allConnectors();
        for ( Connector connector : connectors )
        {
            if ( connector.name().equals( "com.sun.jdi.CommandLineLaunch" ) )
            {
                return ( LaunchingConnector ) connector;
            }
        }
        throw new Error( "No launching connector" );
    }

    private Map<String, Argument> connectorArguments( LaunchingConnector connector, String mainArgs )
    {
        final Map<String, Argument> arguments = connector.defaultArguments();
        final Argument mainArg = arguments.get( "main" );
        final Argument optionArg = arguments.get( "options" );
        if ( mainArg == null )
        {
            throw new Error( "Bad launching connector" );
        }
        if ( optionArg == null )
        {
            throw new Error( "Bad launching connector" );
        }
        mainArg.setValue( mainArgs );
        optionArg.setValue( "-classic" );
        return arguments;
    }

    private void setEventRequests()
    {
        final EventRequestManager mgr = vm.eventRequestManager();
        final ExceptionRequest exceptionRequest = mgr.createExceptionRequest( null, true, true );
        final MethodEntryRequest methodEntryRequest = mgr.createMethodEntryRequest();
        final MethodExitRequest methodExitRequest = mgr.createMethodExitRequest();
        final ThreadStartRequest threadStartRequest = mgr.createThreadStartRequest();
        final ThreadDeathRequest threadDeathRequest = mgr.createThreadDeathRequest();
        final ClassPrepareRequest classPrepareRequest = mgr.createClassPrepareRequest();
        for ( String include : this.includes )
        {
            methodEntryRequest.addClassFilter( include );
            methodExitRequest.addClassFilter( include );
            classPrepareRequest.addClassFilter( include );
        }
        for ( String exclude : this.excludes )
        {
            methodEntryRequest.addClassExclusionFilter( exclude );
            methodExitRequest.addClassExclusionFilter( exclude );
            classPrepareRequest.addClassExclusionFilter( exclude );
        }
        exceptionRequest.setSuspendPolicy( EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL );
        methodEntryRequest.setSuspendPolicy( EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL );
        methodExitRequest.setSuspendPolicy( EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL );
        threadStartRequest.setSuspendPolicy( EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL );
        threadDeathRequest.setSuspendPolicy( EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL );
        classPrepareRequest.setSuspendPolicy( EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL );
        exceptionRequest.enable();
        methodEntryRequest.enable();
        methodExitRequest.enable();
        threadStartRequest.enable();
        threadDeathRequest.enable();
        classPrepareRequest.enable();
        setupJdiEventListener();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        this.writer = new PrintWriter( System.out );
//        initTree(  );
        try
        {
            launch();
            buildProcessTree();
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setupJdiEventListener()
    {
        reader = new EventReader( "EventReader", vm.eventQueue() );
        reader.addEventListener( this );
    }

    protected void buildProcessTree()
    {
        try
        {
            boolean goOn = true;
            EventQueue queue = vm.eventQueue();
            EventSet eventSet;
            EventIterator it;
            while ( !stop && this.connected && goOn )
            {
                try
                {
                    eventSet = queue.remove();
                    it = eventSet.eventIterator();
                    while ( it.hasNext() )
                    {
                    }
                    eventSet.resume();
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException exc )
                {
                    System.out.println( "Logic.Converter.EventThread -> run -> InterruptedException" );
                }
                catch ( VMDisconnectedException discExc )
                {
                    //  this.handleDisconnectedException();
                    System.out.println( "Logic.Converter.EventThread -> run -> VMDisconnectedException" );
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( stop )
            {
                this.vm.exit( 0 );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( "Logic.Converter.EventThread -> run -> Exception" );
        }
    }
```

AbstractReader.java

```
*/**
 * An abstract reader that continuously reads.
 */

abstract public class AbstractReader
{
    protected String name;
    protected Thread readerThread;
    protected boolean isStopping = false;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param name
     */
    public AbstractReader( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Continuously reads. Note that if the read involves waiting
     * it can be interrupted and a InterruptedException will be thrown.
     */
    abstract protected void readerLoop();

    /**
     * Start the thread that reads events.
     *
     */
    public void start()
    {
        readerThread = new Thread( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                readerLoop();
            }
        }, name );

        readerThread.setDaemon( true );
        readerThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Tells the reader loop that it should stop.
     */
    public void stop()
    {
        isStopping = true;
        if ( readerThread != null )
        {
            readerThread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

EventReader.java

```
/**
 * An event reader that continuously reads events coming from the VM
 * and dispatch them to the registered listeners.
 *
 */
public class EventReader extends AbstractReader
{
    private EventQueue eventQueue;

    private Vector<JdiEventListener> jdiEventListeners = new Vector<JdiEventListener>();

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param name
     * @param queue
     */
    public EventReader( String name, EventQueue queue )
    {
        super( name );

        eventQueue = queue;
    }

    /**
     * Registers the given event listener.
     * @param listener
     */
    public synchronized void addEventListener( JdiEventListener listener )
    {
        jdiEventListeners.addElement( listener );
    }

    /**
     * Dispatches the given event to the given listener.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed.
     */
    private boolean dispatch( Event event, JdiEventListener listener )
    {
        if ( event instanceof AccessWatchpointEvent )
        {
            return listener.accessWatchpoint( ( AccessWatchpointEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof BreakpointEvent )
        {
            return listener.breakpoint( ( BreakpointEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof ClassPrepareEvent )
        {
            return listener.classPrepare( ( ClassPrepareEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof ClassUnloadEvent )
        {
            return listener.classUnload( ( ClassUnloadEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof ExceptionEvent )
        {
            return listener.exception( ( ExceptionEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof MethodEntryEvent )
        {
            return listener.methodEntry( ( MethodEntryEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof MethodExitEvent )
        {
            return listener.methodExit( ( MethodExitEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof ModificationWatchpointEvent )
        {
            return listener.modificationWatchpoint( ( ModificationWatchpointEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof StepEvent )
        {
            return listener.step( ( StepEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof ThreadDeathEvent )
        {
            return listener.threadDeath( ( ThreadDeathEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof ThreadStartEvent )
        {
            return listener.threadStart( ( ThreadStartEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof VMDisconnectEvent )
        {
            return listener.vmDisconnect( ( VMDisconnectEvent ) event );
        }
        if ( event instanceof VMDeathEvent )
        {
            return listener.vmDeath( ( VMDeathEvent ) event );
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Continuously reads events that are coming from the event queue.
     */
    protected void readerLoop()
    {
        while ( !isStopping )
        {
            try
            {
                if ( !isStopping )
                {
                    // Get the next event
                    EventSet eventSet = eventQueue.remove();

                    // Dispatch the events
                    boolean shouldGo = true;
                    EventIterator iterator = eventSet.eventIterator();
                    while ( iterator.hasNext() )
                    {
                        Event event = iterator.nextEvent();
                        for ( int i = 0; i < jdiEventListeners.size(); i++ )
                        {
                            JdiEventListener listener = jdiEventListeners.elementAt( i );
                            shouldGo = shouldGo & dispatch( event, listener );
                        }
                        if ( event instanceof VMDeathEvent )
                        {
                            stop();
                        }
                    }

                    // Let the VM go if it was interrupted
                    if ( ( !isStopping )
                            && ( eventSet != null )
                            && ( eventSet.suspendPolicy() == EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL )
                            && shouldGo )
                    {
                        synchronized ( this )
                        {
                            eventQueue.virtualMachine().resume();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                if ( !isStopping )
                {
                    System.out.println( "Event reader loop was interrupted" );
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch ( VMDisconnectedException e )
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * De-registers the given event listener.
     * @param listener
     */
    public synchronized void removeEventListener( JdiEventListener listener )
    {
        jdiEventListeners.removeElement( listener );
    }
}
```

JdiEventListener.java

```
/**
 * An event listener that handles all kinds of event coming from the VM.
 */
public interface JdiEventListener
{
    /**
     * Handles an access watchpoint event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean accessWatchpoint(AccessWatchpointEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a breakpoint event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean breakpoint(BreakpointEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a class prepare event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean classPrepare(ClassPrepareEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a class unload event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean classUnload(ClassUnloadEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles an exception event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean exception(ExceptionEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a method entry event
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean methodEntry(MethodEntryEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a method exit event
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean methodExit(MethodExitEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a modification watchpoint event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean modificationWatchpoint(ModificationWatchpointEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a step event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean step(StepEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a thread death event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean threadDeath(ThreadDeathEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a thread start event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean threadStart(ThreadStartEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a vm death event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean vmDeath(VMDeathEvent event);
    /**
     * Handles a vm disconnect event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     * @param event
     * @return whether the VM should be resumed if it was interrupted.
     */
    public boolean vmDisconnect(VMDisconnectEvent event);
}
```

JdiEventWaiter.java

```
/**
 * Listen for a specific kind of event.
 */
public class JdiEventWaiter implements JdiEventListener
{
    protected EventRequest request;
    protected boolean shouldGo;
    protected Event event;

    /**
     * Creates a new EventWaiter for the given request. Sets whether it
     * should let the VM go after it got the event.
     * @param request
     * @param shouldGo
     */
    public JdiEventWaiter( EventRequest request, boolean shouldGo )
    {
        this.request = request;
        this.shouldGo = shouldGo;
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean accessWatchpoint( AccessWatchpointEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean methodEntry( MethodEntryEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean methodExit( MethodExitEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean breakpoint( BreakpointEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean classPrepare( ClassPrepareEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean classUnload( ClassUnloadEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean exception( ExceptionEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     * Handles an incoming event.
     * Returns whether the VM should be resumed if it was suspended.
     */
    protected boolean handleEvent( Event event )
    {
        if ( ( event.request() != null ) && ( event.request().equals( request ) ) )
        {
            notifyEvent( event );
            return shouldGo;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean modificationWatchpoint( ModificationWatchpointEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     * Notify any object that is waiting for an event.
     */
    synchronized protected void notifyEvent( Event event )
    {
        notify();
        this.event = event;
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean step( StepEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean threadDeath( ThreadDeathEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean threadStart( ThreadStartEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean vmDeath( VMDeathEvent event )
    {
        if ( event == null )
        {
            // This is the last event we can ever get an this was not the one we expected
            notifyEvent( null );
            return true;
        }

        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     */
    public boolean vmDisconnect( VMDisconnectEvent event )
    {
        return handleEvent( event );
    }

    /**
     * Waits for the first event corresponding to this waiter's request.
     * @return if the vm should be restarted
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    synchronized public Event waitEvent() throws InterruptedException
    {
        if ( event == null ) // If event didn't already come in
        {
            wait();
        }
        Event result = event;
        event = null;

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Waits for the first event corresponding to this waiter's request
     * for the given time (in ms). If it times out, return null.
     * @param time
     * @return if the vm should be restarted or not
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    synchronized public Event waitEvent( long time )
            throws InterruptedException
    {
        if ( event == null ) // If event didn't already come in
        {
            wait( time );
        }
        Event result = event;
        event = null;
        return result;
    }
}
```

P.S.
Имеет смысл не вызывать кучу удалённых методов, а просто запустить удаленное приложение, которое содержит и выполняет Ваш код естественным образом, т.е. для того примера, что Вы приводите, можно сделать следующее:

Код, добавленный к удалённому приложению:

```
    public class A {
        public static long freeMemory(){
           Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
           return runtime.freeMemory();
        }
    }
```

Алгоритм для Вашего приложения:

- Получить `ReferenceType` для класса `A`;
- Получить метод `A.freeMemory()`;
- Удалённо вызвать метод `A.freeMemory()`;

Comment: Не уловил суть подхода.. Во-первых, эти манипуляции хотелось бы уметь проводить на запущенном приложении (не обязательно, что есть его сорс-код). Во-вторых, я не понял, в чем принципиальная разница между моим и вашим  вариантом. У вас я вижу простое делегирование..

Comment: @EvgenyLazarev Подход в том, чтобы выполнять сложные процедуры на запущенном приложении удалённо вызывая один метод. РАзница не принципиальная пожалуй

Comment: @EvgenyLazarev Я добавил несколько листингов из моего приложения, касающихся работы с ивентами и тредами, Надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Постараюсь разобраться в этом коде (кстати, он мне показался очень знакомым; кажется, когда я искал материал по теме, где то видел что то похожее)

Comment: Незашто. Естественно,примеры c jdi  я  нагуглил, а также заглянул в http://users.dsic.upv.es/~jsilva/DDJ/, но правда здесь в отлаживаемом приложении многопоточность не рассматривается.